# Total War: Shogun 2 doesn't use NVIDIA card on linux

Tags: linux, shogun-2-total-war

Since Total War: Shogun 2 was recently ported to Linux, I decided to install it on my laptop running Arch Linux which has an integrated Intel graphics card (Intel HD 5500) as well as an additional NVIDIA card (NVIDIA GForce 940M), which are setup using bumblebee. However, when  starting the game using `primusrun`, the game doesn't actually seem to use the dedicated card (entering the video settings in-game shows me that the Intel card is used). Upon researching further, I found out that the game uses a shellscript named `Shogun2.sh` to launch itself, and sure enough, running `fuser -v /usr/lib/primus/libGL.so.1` shows that `Shogun2.sh` has actually loaded the `libGl.so.1` from primusrun, but this doesn't seem to extend to the actual binary. Then again, running `tr \\0 \\n < /proc/8044/environ` (where 8044 is the PID of the binary) shows that `/usr/$LIB/primus` is actually a part of `LD_PRELOAD`.

I have tried inserting the `primusrun` command into the shellscript so that the binary is executed through it, but to no success.
Another method I thought about was using the "Advanced options" field in the Feral launcher that seems to be baked into the binary and seems to be required to launch the game, but I was unable to find any documentation on supported switches/syntax.

Is there any way to enable the dedicated GPU for Shogun 2: Total War on linux?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

After trying some different things and getting deeper into the innards of the game files, I realized that I didn't have the 32-bit version of primus installed. After fixing this, the game now recognizes the dedicated NVIDIA card.

Comment: @2A-66-42, please write your own answer instead of hijacking someone else's.